# How to fix column names of source destination?

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to load an excel sheet into my database, lets say there's only one column in the excel sheet named `NAME` which maps to `NAME` in the database.  Sometimes however, I'll get an excel sheet with column `Name` which throws an error since it's case sensitive.  Is there a way to either uppercase the column name or have a 2nd mapping? What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Excel Connection allows you to script SQL statements that are not case sensitive. So Select NAME as NAME from Sheet1$ will always result in a UPPER case name being taken into SSIS

Comment: Alternatively, if columns are alway in same order, then skip the header row and name the rows yourself. They will be read as F1,F2.... and can be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Cause i'm curious how it's look in reality, i make test in python:

```
import datetime, time
name_dict = ['name','Name','NAME','NAMe','NAme','NamE','NaME']
name = 'Name'
z=0
x=0

for z in range(0,5):    
    start= time.time()
    for x in range(1,10000000):
        if name_dict[2].upper() == "NAME":
            None
    stop=time.time()    
    print('Try no. '+str(z)+' Upper test:'+str(stop-start))

for z in range(0,5):
    start= time.time()
    for x in range(1,10000000):
        if name in name_dict:
            None
    stop=time.time()
    print('Try no. '+str(z)+' Search in dict test:'+str(stop-start))
```

Results

```
Try no. 0 Upper test:1.3549904823303223
Try no. 1 Upper test:1.356055736541748
Try no. 2 Upper test:1.3510148525238037
Try no. 3 Upper test:1.3499987125396729
Try no. 4 Upper test:1.3550000190734863
Try no. 0 Search in dict test:0.7339987754821777
Try no. 1 Search in dict test:0.738067626953125
Try no. 2 Search in dict test:0.7309765815734863
Try no. 3 Search in dict test:0.7490558624267578
Try no. 4 Search in dict test:0.7480108737945557
```

In python search in dict is faster.